# What is the maximum number of websites that can exist?

Tags: domain, website

I know there must be an upper limit for the number of websites that can exist. But what is it? I can't think of something that I can consider the permutations to arrive at an answer

Edit 1: For some reason, people aren't liking my question even though it's a genuine question and out of curiosity.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Your question is getting downvotes because it does not show any homework, and it appears to disregard the general purpose of SuperUser, which is to solve computer problems, not explore computer trivia. I did not know the answer to this question, but spent about 8 minutes thinking and then searching and finding the answers to the few criteria which govern this.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for giving an answer as I was generally confused. To be honest, I was afraid it might not belong here but in the FAQ section of SuperUser the following is written, 'Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users'. Which why I thought my question would fit here because it's not per se a field in-depth question but a computer enthusiast could answer it as pointed out by your answer. I was missing the information that it has to do with the DNS and you knew it.

Comment: One way to avoid the down/close votes then would have been to tell us what you know, what you've researched, and what gaps you can identify in your knowledge. This covers the "done your own homework" aspect of a good question. Computer power users can have questions that are not about computers within the bounds of our guidelines, and plenty of "genuine" questions are still off topic here. I'm a 20 year IT professional, and I have lots of questions that don't belong here.

Comment: SuperUser's allowed topic list does have a lot of grey areas, and a well-presented question that is arguably off-topic can survive because it is well presented. Even though you've got the answer you're looking for, you can go back and EDIT your question to add the thought process you went through before coming here and how you knew your initial estimates may have been missing information or incorrect. Doing this will push off lots of future down/close votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is relatively simply math based on known quantities.

First you need to know the maximum length of of the DNS part of a URL, and that's 253 characters, more or less: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290167/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-dns-name/32294443

Next you need to know the number of characters allowed in DNS names. Assuming [case-INsensitivity to be safe](https://serverfault.com/questions/261341/is-the-hostname-case-sensitive), this number is 37 (26 alpha characters, 10 numerics, and the dash).

So, you then use the mathematics of Permutations to multiply these together, and it's basically going to be 37 raise to the 253rd power, or 37^253.

My calculator says this is about **5.6890033427332663734314647832695e+396**